# TypeError in Python: "init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fov'" when creating an instance of a Camera class

Tags: python, class

I'm working on a 3D rendering application in Python and encountered an issue when trying to create an instance of the Camera class. The error message I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: Camera.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fov'
```

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
class Scene():
    def __init__(self, ambient_color = vec3(0.01, 0.01, 0.01), n = vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0)) :
        # n = index of refraction (by default index of refraction of air n = 1.)
        self.scene_primitives = []
        self.collider_list = []
        self.shadowed_collider_list = []
        self.Light_list = []
        self.importance_sampled_list = []
        self.ambient_color = ambient_color
        self.n = n
        self.importance_sampled_list = []
    def add_Camera(self, look_from, look_at, **kwargs):
        self.camera = Camera(look_from, look_at, up_vector=vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0), fov=60.0, aspect_ratio=16.0 / 9.0, **kwargs)
class Camera():
    def __init__(self, look_from, look_at,up_vector,fov, aspect_ratio, screen_width = 400 ,screen_height = 300,  field_of_view = 90., aperture = 0., focal_distance = 1.):
        self.fov = fov
        self.aspect_ratio = aspect_ratio
        self.up_vector = up_vector
        self.screen_width = screen_width
        self.screen_height = screen_height
        self.aspect_ratio = float(screen_width) / screen_height
        self.look_from = look_from
        self.look_at = look_at
        self.camera_width = np.tan(field_of_view * np.pi/180   /2.)*2.
        self.camera_height = self.camera_width/self.aspect_ratio
        self.cameraFwd = (look_at - look_from).normalize()
        self.cameraRight = (self.cameraFwd.cross(vec3(0.,1.,0.))).normalize()
        self.cameraUp = self.cameraRight.cross(self.cameraFwd)
        self.lens_radius =  aperture / 2.
        self.focal_distance = focal_distance
        self.x = np.linspace(-self.camera_width/2., self.camera_width/2., self.screen_width)
        self.y = np.linspace(self.camera_height/2., -self.camera_height/2., self.screen_height)
        xx,yy = np.meshgrid(self.x,self.y)
        self.x = xx.flatten()
        self.y = yy.flatten()
My_Scene.add_Camera(look_from = vec3(0*np.sin(angle), 0, 0*np.cos(angle)  -1.5 ),look_at = vec3(0, 0, 0),fov=60.0,aspect_ratio=16.0 / 9.0,up_vector=vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0),screen_width = 300 ,screen_height = 300)
```

Comment: In terms of SOLID design principles, you should create the camera and then use `scene.add_camera(new_camera)`, not pass around parameters used to create objects. That will also help debug what's going wrong and where. For now, please edit your question to include the ***full*** stack trace from your error.

Comment: `Camera.__init__` takes `fov` as a plain positional arg, not as a kwarg.  Either you need to change the `__init__` method to accept `fov` as a kwarg, or you need to not pass it as a kwarg.

Comment: Your call to `add_camera()` supplies a `fov` argument, which is then past to `Camera.__init__()` as part of the kwargs. But you ***also*** pass another `fov` argument inside `add_camera()`. Passing `fov` twice is the cause of your error.

Comment: Also, what is `My_Scene`?  That variable is undefined.  Your code needs to be **complete**, without any undefined variables or missing input, so that we can run it ourselves and see the same error that you see.

Comment: @JohnGordon `My_Scene = Scene(ambient_color = vec3(0.05, 0.05, 0.05))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get a different error:

> TypeError: **main**.Camera() got multiple values for keyword argument 'fov'

The problem is that you have `fov=60.0` in the arguments to `Camera()`, but it's also in `kwargs` because you have it in the arguments to `My_Scene.add_Camera()`.

Merge your default argument values with the ones that are passed in `kwargs`.

```
    def add_Camera(self, look_from, look_at, **kwargs):
        defaults = {'up_vector': vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0), 'fov': 60.0, 'aspect_ratio': 16.0/9.0}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        self.camera = Camera(look_from, look_at, **defaults)
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. But how can i pass those arguments? I mean you set them manually.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you wanted. You want these to be defaults in case they're not in `kwargs`?

Comment: If i got the code right it's setting up_vector to vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0), fov to 60.0 and aspect_ratio to 16.0/9.0 and my problem is you can't change these values. I don't know how to tell you my mind but i want to set for example fov to 30.0. Not in the code but as a changeable argument. I don't know if that makes sense.

Comment: If you call `add_Camera()` with `fov=30.0`, that will now take precedence. `fov=60.0` is the default.